# ggplot2: Group histogram data by year

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, width, bins

I have a bunch of data with a YYYY-MM-DD date attached to it, and I'm having trouble getting a single bar for each year. In other words, all data from 2014 showing up under a bar for 2014.

The dates were converted to the YYYY-MM-DD format using

`df1$Close.Date <- as.Date(df1$Close.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Here's my histogram formula that doesn't group correctly

`ggplot(df1, aes(Close.Date, fill=Stage)) + geom_bar()`

I've tried messing around with `breaks` and `binwidth` with no success

Comment: In the `aes`, where is the `y` variable?

Comment: Besides what @akrun mentioned, you may want to `aggregate` your data by year, otherwise you can get multiple values per year, but we can't be sure since we don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: @Bernardo Thanks! Sometimes the solution is so simple you kick yourself. I added this line `df1$yr <- strftime(df1$Close.Date, "%Y")` and then replaced Close.Date with yr in the ggplot line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by: adding this line `df1$yr <- strftime(df1$Close.Date, "%Y")` and then replacing Close.Date with yr in the ggplot line.